# React native how clear ram when component unmount?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ram

How delete cache(images, item, component), from ram when component unmount?
Now, when a new View is opened, the RAM is not cleared.
After I move on to another activity memory is not cleared and modern is overflowing.
Every time a new component is opened, even if it was previously opened, the amount of memory used increases.
Sorry for my bad english.

```
export default class Articles extends PureComponent {
constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context)
    this.state = {
        renderPlaceholderOnly: true,
        unMountStatus: true,
    }
}

componentWillMount() {
    let { params } = this.props.navigation.state
    this.props.fetchData(params.id)
}

componentDidMount() {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        this.setState({renderPlaceholderOnly: false})
    })
}

componentWillUnMount() {
    this.setState({
        unMountStatus: false
    })
    this.props.dataArticles.data = []
    this.props.unFetchData()
    console.log(this.props)
    this.props = []
    console.log(this.props)
}

_renderPlaceholderView() {
    return (
        <View>
            <Spinner color={'#575757'} visible={true} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#575757'}} />
        </View>
    )
}

_addUrlToCache(url) {
    ImageResizer.createResizedImage(url, 375, 175, 'JPEG', 75, 0)
        .then((resizedImageUri) => {
            cache.put('lalka2', resizedImageUri) 
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
    })
    return cache.get("lalka2")
}

render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation
    console.log(this._addUrlToCache("https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQoiqLLZMXTvg385j12vAs_P9PN3Cv9t3udbBwGnBYwFjC1dPuD"))

    if (this.state.renderPlaceholderOnly) {
        return this._renderPlaceholderView()
    }

    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Header menuOpen={this.openControlPanel} title={'Articles'} navigate={this.props.navigation}/>
            <Spinner color={'#575757'} visible={this.props.dataArticles.isFetching} textContent={"Loading..."} textStyle={{color: '#575757'}} />

            { this.state.unMountStatus ? <ScrollView>
            {
                this.props.dataArticles.data.length > 0 ? this.props.dataArticles.data.map((item, index) => {
                    return (
                        <Card style={{ flex: 0 }} key={index}>
                            <CardItem style={{backgroundColor: 'white', borderColor: '#841010', borderBottomWidth: 1}}>
                                <Left>

                                    <Body>
                                        <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', color: "#841010"}}>{item.title}</Text>
                                        <Text note style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto', color: "#6B0D0D"}}>{item.publishedAt}</Text>
                                    </Body>
                                </Left>
                            </CardItem>
                            <CardItem>
                                <Body>


                                    <Text style={{fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>
                                        {item.description}
                                    </Text>
                                    <Button transparent textStyle={{color: '#87838B', fontSize: 28}} onPress={() => navigate('WebView', { authorArticle: 'Article', url: item.url })}>
                                        <Icon style={{color: "#841010"}} name="link" />
                                        <Text style={{ color: "#841010", fontFamily: 'Roboto'}}>Read More</Text>
                                    </Button>
                                </Body>
                            </CardItem>
                        </Card>
                    )
                }) : <View></View>
        }
            </ScrollView> : null
    }
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems like you already have some source code available. It might be helpful to others to add that to your question.

Comment: Sure you didn't mean `componentWillUnmount` rather than `componentWillUnMount`?

Comment: What do you mean by RAM?

Comment: Random Access Memory